# Frida Gadget configuration value "path" set to "self"

Tags: frida

I recently came across a different way to specify the path to the Javascript file for Frida Gadget to load and execute.

```
{
  "interaction": {
    "type": "script",
    "path": "self"
  }
}
```

I know we can specify relative or absolute file paths but the person used "self" instead.

Does anyone know how that works?

Comment: May be `self` is simply the relative file name that contains the script? Is the app containing the gadget an Android or iOS app and does it contain a file with the same `self`?

Comment: Hi @Robert

From my observation, there is no file named "self". This is an Android APK that has been modified.

The files are stored inside the lib/<architecture> folder so I think Android requires that the files follow a naming convention, namely starts with "lib" and ends with ".so".